# Why are there different defining equations for curvature flow problems? What are the key differences?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

Given an initial hypersurface in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ with position vector $V_0$ there are two ways I have seen to define the evolution of $V_0$ due to a curvature flow;

$$(1) \hspace{1cm} \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\sigma(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)\hat{n}$$

$$\hspace{1cm}(2) \hspace{1cm} \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)^\perp=\sigma(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)\hat{n}$$

Where $V(x,t)$ satisfies one of the above equations and $V_0=V(x,0)$. Here $\sigma$ is a function of principal curvatures and $u^\perp=\langle u,\hat n \rangle \hat{n}$.

I have two questions concerning this.

1. Do these equations provide the same family of hypersurfaces $\{V_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$?
2. How similar are the flows if not the same? For example if I have theorems that hold for (1) do they hold for (2) and vice-versa?

Comment: The solution to the mapping $V$ is different in (1) and (2), but they are differ by only a tangential diffeomorphism on each $M_t$ (as least when $M$ is closed). So geometrically the hypersurfaces are the same.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have a few questions just for clarification if you dont mind.  
Does this mean that there is a diffeomorphism on the tangent bundle of $M^1_t$ ( in the image of (1)) to the tangent bundle of $M^2_t$ (in the image of (2))? So that $M^1_t$ and $M^2_t$ are the same manifold but with different (but diffeomorphic) differentiable structures?

Comment: What I mean is the following: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $V^1,V^2 : M \times [0, T)\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ are solutions to (1), (2) respectively. Then there is a smooth mapping $\Phi : M \times [0,T)\to M$ such that $\Phi (t, \cdot): M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism for each $t$ and $V^1 (t, x) = V^2 (t, \Phi(t, x))$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! This helps greatly. Do you know where i could find a proof/idea of a proof for such a statement? Also if you'd like to give your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.